# Dynamic components in Blender?

Tags: modeling

Summary: I need to make an object which can be changed using parameters. Changes include less or more elements in the object and the position of each. Is this possible in Blender?

For my work I use currently Sketchup, but I am interested in changing to blender.

The question I have is whether it is possible like in SketchUp to use dynamic components. We use this to draw roller conveyors. We have a component where you can change the length and width etc. with parameters.

More easy to understand is an example with staircases. If I make the stair higher, then automatically more steps are generated. If I increase the height of the steps, less steps are needed. Sometime I want a guiding rail on the left or right or both. The steps can be thin metal plates or thicker wooden boards.

Is it possible to create such an object with parameter inside Blender. Is there an video or tutorial available online to see how things work?

An example of what we make can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmNGK_-BJrE

Comment: I am not sure here if you are saying that you use dynamic components or you make your own. If you only use what is there then you are limited to what you can find. In the same way you could use addons some of which are parametric. Looking at your example here is a list to get you started https://www.blender3darchitect.com/python-scripts-for-archviz/list-of-add-ons-for-architectural-visualization-with-blender/ some you will need to install some are already installed. If you make your own dynamic components then you could learn the same with python in Blender

Comment: In SketchUp I make my own. From your remark I understand that in Blender this is only possible using coding. In the meantime I found a video explaining a add on for stairs, where the guy mentions it crashes is you use too many steps (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5UrVrmErwQ). BTW thanks for your response!